# Using reflection to alter WebView causes segfault (Fatal signal 11)

Tags: android, reflection, android-webview

I am using reflection in an Android application to alter the behaviour of a WebView. From browsing the Android source, each WebView has, through a chain of objects, a Handler which tells the native code to fetch resources, among other things.

What I am trying to do is replace this Handler with my own, which alters some of the messages it receives, then passes the message to the original Handler. Specifically, I need to rewrite some of the URLs so they are configured for a proxy.

Here is a dummy method to demonstrate this:

```
private static boolean relayWebViewHandler( WebView webView ) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Attempting");

    try {
        Class classWV = Class.forName( "android.webkit.WebView" );
        Field mProviderField = classWV.getDeclaredField( "mProvider" );
        Object webViewClassic = getFieldValueSafely( mProviderField, webView );

        Class classWVCl = Class.forName( "android.webkit.WebViewClassic" );
        Field mWebViewCoreField = classWVCl.getDeclaredField( "mWebViewCore" );
        Object webViewCore = getFieldValueSafely( mWebViewCoreField, webViewClassic );

        Class classWVCo = Class.forName( "android.webkit.WebViewCore" );
        Field mEventHubField = classWVCo.getDeclaredField( "mEventHub" );
        Object eventHub = getFieldValueSafely( mEventHubField, webViewCore );

        Class classEH = Class.forName( "android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub" );
        Field mHandlerField = classEH.getDeclaredField( "mHandler" );
        final Handler handler = (Handler) getFieldValueSafely( mHandlerField, eventHub );

        Handler relayHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage( Message msg ) {
                Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Relayed a message!" );
                handler.handleMessage( msg );
            }
        };
        setFieldValueSafely( mHandlerField, eventHub, relayHandler );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e( LOG_TAG, "Failed with error: " + e.getMessage() );
        return false;
    }

    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Successful!" );
    return true;
}

private static Object getFieldValueSafely( Field field, Object classInstance ) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    boolean oldAccessibleValue = field.isAccessible();
    field.setAccessible( true );
    Object result = field.get( classInstance );
    field.setAccessible( oldAccessibleValue );
    return result;
}

private static void setFieldValueSafely( Field field, Object classInstance, Object value ) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    boolean oldAccessibleValue = field.isAccessible();
    field.setAccessible( true );
    field.set( classInstance, value );
    field.setAccessible( oldAccessibleValue );
}
```

When I run this on a 4.3 emulator, LogCat shows a few "Relayed a message!" notifications, then the Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) error, each time at a different address.

I know this means a segfault, but I'm not sure how replacing a Handler object used by the WebViewCore would cause this. Has anyone any knowledge or experience in this matter? Does the native code not have access to objects I've created? Am I meddling in things that ought not to be meddled in?

Comment: "Am I meddling in things that ought not to be meddled in?" -- most certainly yes.